# Can't position HTML elements using bootstrap v4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have header tag inside the header I have one container for logo and one container for login form. I want my logo to be left and my login form to be position top right angle, but when I set `float-left` to the logo container and `float-right` to the login form they break. I've made sure the containers to be enough sized to fit in, but they still break.

Here is my code:

```
<header class="bg-inverse text-white col-sm-12" style="border: 1px solid blue">

  <div id="logo" class="col-sm-8"style="border:1px solid red">
    <h1 class="font-weight-bold">Somelogo</h1>
  </div>

  <div id="login-form" class="col-sm-3">
    <form class="" style="border: 1px solid blue">
      <div class="form-group mb-0">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="username">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group mb-1">
        <label class="pt-1 mb-0" for="Password" style="border: 1px solid blue">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="password">
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-5 btn-sm">register</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-5 btn-sm">login</button>

    </form>
  </div>

</header>
```

This is how to looks like without setting a position [Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T2oy.png)

This is how it looks when I set `float:left` to the div with id `logo` and `float:right` to the div with id `login-form`[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSpOW.png)

This is with only setting the div with id `login-form` to `float-right`[Picture 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfwUy.png)

PS: I'm trying to use only bootstrap 4. And please explain what is the problem, why is this happening.

Comment: Adding http://jsfiddle.net snippet would be better than pictures :)

Comment: @RafałWarzycha jsfiddle is a third party site. His images are posted through a Stack Overflow endorsed method. Do not use jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you aren's using the Bootstrap grid correctly. This is a common beginner mistake.

Bootstrap rows and columns are designed to work **together**.

That means: You cannot nest a Bootstrap column directly into another Bootstrap column. If you do, you'll inevitably run into issues as is the case here.

Solution:

When nesting anything inside a Bootstrap column, first put a div (or another suitable HTML element) with the class `.row` into that column and then put a div with the class `.col` into that row div.

WRONG:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="col"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

RIGHT:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This option would also work fine:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I suspect the following is the layout you wanted to create:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <header class="bg-inverse col-sm-12" style="border: 1px solid blue">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="logo" class="col-sm-8" style="border:1px solid red">
                    <h1 class="font-weight-bold">Somelogo</h1>
                </div>
                <div id="login-form" class="col-sm-3 offset-sm-1">
                    <form class="" style="border: 1px solid blue">
                        <div class="form-group mb-0">
                            <label for="username">Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group mb-1">
                            <label class="pt-1 mb-0" for="Password" style="border: 1px solid blue">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="password">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-5 btn-sm mb-2 mb-sm-0">register</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-5 btn-sm">login</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Note:

I had added the `.container-fluid` class and removed the `.text-white` class in the code snippet above.

P.S. I'm adding another version here that I think is better than the previous but it really depends on what you actually want. Here it is:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">


<header class="bg-inverse" style="border: 1px solid blue">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid blue">
            <div id="logo" class="col-sm-8" style="border:1px solid red">
                <h1 class="font-weight-bold">Somelogo</h1>
            </div>
            <div id="login-form" class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 offset-lg-1">
                <form class="" style="border: 1px solid blue">
                    <div class="form-group mb-0">
                        <label for="username">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group mb-1">
                        <label class="pt-1 mb-0" for="Password" style="border: 1px solid blue">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-5 btn-sm mb-2 mb-sm-0">register</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-5 btn-sm">login</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Everything is so easy now that I understand the row column concept. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following solution, using the [flex utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/) of Bootstrap 4:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="bg-dark text-white col-sm-12 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" style="border: 1px solid blue">
  <div id="logo" class="col-sm-8" style="border:1px solid red">
    <h1 class="font-weight-bold">Somelogo</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="login-form" class="col-sm-3">
    <form style="border: 1px solid blue">
      <div class="form-group mb-0">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group mb-1">
        <label class="pt-1 mb-0" for="Password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="password">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-5 btn-sm">register</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-5 btn-sm">login</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</header>
```

Another solution using [`.container` and `.row`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header class="container bg-dark text-white col-sm-12" style="border: 1px solid blue">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="logo" class="col-sm-8 align-self-center mr-auto" style="border:1px solid red">
      <h1 class="font-weight-bold">Somelogo</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="login-form" class="col-sm-3">
      <form style="border: 1px solid blue">
        <div class="form-group mb-0">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="username">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-1">
          <label class="pt-1 mb-0" for="Password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-5 btn-sm">register</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-5 btn-sm">login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: A Bootstrap-based solution really ought to impart proper usage of the framework; you're applying `d-flex` to Grid columns and completely ignoring the proper usage of `container` and `row` which will only teach the OP the incorrect way to use Bootstrap.